# Executuing 'grub-install /dev/nvme0n1' failed - This is a fatal error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, 20.04

I am trying to dual boot and I have 2 SSDs one has Windows and on the other one I want to install Kubuntu 20.04 and it's giving me Executing

```
grub-install /dev/nvme0n1' failed - This is a fatal error
```

But when I do with UEFI and with boot partition its works but I don't know why it won't let me change grub.

How can I fix that error so I can install it without UEFI?

Comment: What type of partitioning is on that second disk -- gpt or msdos?  If gpt, for a legacy install you will need a small bios-grub partition (2M, M not G) for the pieces of grub that no longer fit between the partitions, like they do on MSDOS.

Comment: Did you solve it?